# Pivot Table overlapping error

Tags: pivot-table

I have one Pivot Table (that used to have numerous PT's) in a sheet.

When I try to refresh, 'A Pivot Table cannot overlap another Pivot Table' error appears.

As there is only one PT in the sheet, it cannot possibly overlap.

Any suggestions as to how I can fix this issue?

I have never used Macros before so unsure if that would be relevant to my issue.

Thanks in advance,
Lauren.

Comment: possible duplicate http://superuser.com/questions/438751/how-can-i-use-multiple-pivot-tables-on-the-same-sheet-without-an-overlap-error